# Dependency resolution problem: libgnome-keyring0

Tags: 12.04, package-management

I'm trying to install `ia32-libs` on Precise (it's a dependency of CrossOverPro which is actually what I'm trying to achieve, but I don't think that's relevant). That package won't install, and tracing through the chain of reported unmet dependencies, I get to `libgnome-keyring0`, which won't install because of two unmet dependencies, both of which appear to be installed. Which leaves me not knowing how to proceed.

Here's a log of the steps I went through:

```
[~] 
ian@ian-desktop $ sudo apt-get clean
[~] 
ian@ian-desktop $ sudo apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
[~] 
ian@ian-desktop $ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
[~] 
ian@ian-desktop $ sudo apt-get update
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise InRelease
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg     
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise InRelease      
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports InRelease
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security InRelease
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources         
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg [198 B]
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release [49.6 kB]
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release [49.6 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release [49.6 kB]            
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security Release [49.6 kB]               
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Sources [934 kB]                  
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_GB                     
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Sources [5,470 B]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Sources [5,019 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Sources [155 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main amd64 Packages [1,273 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted amd64 Packages [8,452 B]                       
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe amd64 Packages [4,786 kB]                        
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse amd64 Packages [119 kB]                        
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main i386 Packages [1,274 kB]                             
Get:18 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted i386 Packages [8,431 B]                        
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe i386 Packages [4,796 kB]                         
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse i386 Packages [121 kB]                         
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main TranslationIndex                                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse TranslationIndex                                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted TranslationIndex                                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe TranslationIndex                                    
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Sources [11.8 kB]                            
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Sources [765 B]                        
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Sources [4,206 B]                        
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Sources [14 B]                         
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main amd64 Packages [35.7 kB]                     
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [757 B]                 
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe amd64 Packages [11.5 kB]                 
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [14 B]                  
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main i386 Packages [37.0 kB]                      
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted i386 Packages [770 B]                  
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe i386 Packages [11.5 kB]                  
Get:32 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [14 B]                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main TranslationIndex                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse TranslationIndex                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted TranslationIndex                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe TranslationIndex                            
Get:33 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Sources [700 B]                            
Get:34 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Sources [14 B]                       
Get:35 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Sources [14 B]                         
Get:36 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Sources [14 B]                       
Get:37 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main amd64 Packages [559 B]                     
Get:38 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]                
Get:39 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe amd64 Packages [14 B]                  
Get:40 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages [14 B]                
Get:41 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main i386 Packages [559 B]                      
Get:42 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]                 
Get:43 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe i386 Packages [14 B]                   
Get:44 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse i386 Packages [14 B]                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main TranslationIndex                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse TranslationIndex                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted TranslationIndex                        
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe TranslationIndex                          
Get:45 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Sources [3,873 B]                           
Get:46 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Sources [14 B]                        
Get:47 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Sources [2,143 B]                       
Get:48 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Sources [14 B]                        
Get:49 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main amd64 Packages [17.9 kB]                    
Get:50 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]                 
Get:51 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe amd64 Packages [3,186 B]                
Get:52 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [14 B]                 
Get:53 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main i386 Packages [17.9 kB]                     
Get:54 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]                  
Get:55 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe i386 Packages [3,190 B]                 
Get:56 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse i386 Packages [14 B]                  
Get:57 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main TranslationIndex [72 B]                     
Get:58 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse TranslationIndex [70 B]               
Get:59 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted TranslationIndex [70 B]               
Get:60 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe TranslationIndex [72 B]                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en_GB                                       
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/main Translation-en                                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en_GB                                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/multiverse Translation-en                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en_GB                                 
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/restricted Translation-en                                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en_GB                                   
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise/universe Translation-en                                      
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/main Translation-en                                  
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/multiverse Translation-en                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/restricted Translation-en                            
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates/universe Translation-en                              
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/main Translation-en                                
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/multiverse Translation-en                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/restricted Translation-en                          
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports/universe Translation-en                            
Get:61 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/main Translation-en [7,050 B]                    
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/multiverse Translation-en                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/restricted Translation-en                           
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com precise-security/universe Translation-en                             
Fetched 18.9 MB in 13s (1,386 kB/s)                                                                
Reading package lists... Done
[~] 
ian@ian-desktop $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
[~] 
ian@ian-desktop $ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
[~] 
ian@ian-desktop $ sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 ia32-libs-multiarch:i386 : Depends: gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
[~] 
ian@ian-desktop $ sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 gstreamer0.10-plugins-good:i386 : Depends: libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386 (>= 2.27.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
[~] 
ian@ian-desktop $ sudo apt-get install libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libsoup-gnome2.4-1:i386 : Depends: libgnome-keyring0:i386 (>= 2.20.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
[~] 
ian@ian-desktop $ sudo apt-get install libgnome-keyring0:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 libgnome-keyring0:i386 : Depends: libgnome-keyring-common:i386 (= 3.2.2-2)
 libpurple0 : Depends: libfarstream-0.1-0 (>= 0.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
[~] 
ian@ian-desktop $ sudo apt-get install  libgnome-keyring-common:i386  libfarstream-0.1-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libgnome-keyring-common' instead of 'libgnome-keyring-common:i386'
libfarstream-0.1-0 is already the newest version.
libgnome-keyring-common is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
[~] 
ian@ian-desktop $
```

Parenthetically, I have no idea why `libpurple0` shows up in the last-but-one step.

So there's clearly something amiss in my package structure, but I'm not sure how to go about debugging it or resolving the root cause.

Comment: Try "sudo apt-get install -f"

Comment: Thanks, but `-f` didn't make any difference.

Comment: Hmmm.. That usually resolves the dependency problems. How about "sudo dpkg --configure -a"?

Answer (score 0):

Open up synaptic and type their name(not complete names, just partial names like `keyring` or `libgnome-keyring` or `libfar` etc) in search . You **might** find that those packages have some `-dev` files also. Try installing them. In most cases that solves the problem